# The best way to understand conditional sentences?

Tags: conditionals

I've been learning about conditional sentences and I want to propose my understanding and I hope somebody would tell me if these are wrong.

**1. If X aux. verb, X *would have* Y** always uses auxilary verb **had**

E.g.:

1. I didn't vote in the election, but if I **had**, I **would have** voted for Senator Todd.
2. I called my husband to tell him I would be late. If I **hadn't**, he **would have** gotten worried about me.

**2. If the question starts with "Are"** the negative answer must be **No, but if X *were***

E.g.:

1. **Are** you hungry? No, but if I **were** ....

**3. If the question starts with "Do"** the negative answer must be **No, but if X *did***

E.g.:

1. **Do** you speak Spanish? No, but if I **did** ....

**4. If the question starts with "Did"** the negative answer must be **No, but if X *had***

E.g.:

1. **Did** you forget to bring your grammar book? No, but if I **had** ....

That's all. I need to know whether my understanding is correct or not and please correct me with an example, so I can understand the topic.

Note: **X** is a subject and **Y** is an arbitrary thing that being done by X.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to restrict this question a little...

Comment: Not sure if any of your rules are so fixed. Do you speak Spanish? No, but if I *had learned* some in school, I'd remember at least a little."

Comment: Ask one question at a time, not four.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Sorry but it's not four. I'm asking those 4 forms to compare each other in one topic "conditional sentence". If I ask separately, how do i know the difference? And how do I understand? Only people who can understand this topic not a book. Because I can just learn by myself if it's just one case. I have difficulty to differentiate those 4 forms. And also as Yosef's reply, he gave an example using I had on 3rd form. And from that, maybe I and other people who care can discuss it and compare with other forms. Still don't understand why there's a downvote there.

Comment: @user516076 Yes, you'll find people willing to help you no matter how you violate the rules, but that's a risky way to go. You're supposed to ask one tightly-focused question here. You didn't do that. That's why I said what I said AND downvoted you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your rules are incorrect in that they are overstated as absolute requirements.

All of your examples are correct, but there are other things that could be written, e.g.:

1. If I were you, I would have voted for Senator Todd.
2. No, I'm not.
3. No, I don't.
4. No, I didn't forget.